# I have multiple files named as 1R1.fasta, 1R2.fasta..... 1000R1.fasta. How to concatenate them using loop using python

Tags: python, concatenation

I have bunch of files named as 1R1.fasta, 1R2.fasta, 1R3.fasta........ 5000R1.fasta, 5000R2.fasta, 5000R3.fasta. I am required to concatenate files having same number in one file such as:
cat 1R1.fasta 1R2.fasta 1R3.fasta > 1R.fasta
cat 2R1.fasta 2R2.fasta 2R3.fasta > 2R.fasta

But, since there are numerous files, is there anyway i can use a loop in python to concatenate files.

Answer (score 1):

Since fasta files can be huge, I would probably do this in a bash script. Python is not the best tool for the job.

If your business logic is complex enough to warrant a Python script, try installing the `sh` package to keep the I/O out of Python code:

```
import glob
from sh import cat

for i in range(1, 5001):
    prefix = '%sR' % i
    fasta_files = glob.glob('%s*.fasta' % prefix)
    cat(*fasta_files, _out='%s.fasta' % prefix)
```

Be aware that there's a limit to how many filename arguments `cat` can take.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I have many files and hence was wondering if the script can be automated so that the prefix takes value starting from 1 till 5000. I am very new to the bash scripts, although i have used some for renaming the fasta headers and splitting the multi-fasta files.

Comment: Sure. I updated the script to loop over prefixes 1R..5000R.

Comment: Thank yo so much for your help.